Change the "new tab" page in Microsoft edge
When opening a new tab in Microsoft Edge, either via the keyboard shortcut "Ctrl+T" or via the UI (click "+ New tab", selecting "New tab" from the menu, etc.) the page loaded in the new tab is a Microsoft landing page, with a Bing search box, etc.  I would like to be able to set the URL that new tabs load by default.  Amazingly, I have, so far, been unable to find such a setting in Edge or a solution searching around on Stack Overflow.

UPDATE (2024-12-08):
Shortly after adding my answer, it seems Edge had an update that removed the registry key.  The only way I know of now for changing the new tab URL is to use a browser extension such as "Custom New Tab", which I am now using.

I found an answer to this question in a Reddit, which in turn referenced this blog:
https://www.meziantou.net/set-a-blank-page-for-new-tabs-in-microsoft-edge.htm
I like Stack Overflow, however, so I wanted to have the question and answer available here.  The solution is a registry hack (wow Microsoft, really?).  You can either manually update the registry or run the following command in PowerShell (running as Administrator):
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge" -Name "NewTabPageLocation" -Value "google.com" -PropertyType String -Force

Note that the example above sets new tabs to load www.google.com by default, so change that as needed for your desired behavior.
For me the change took effect immediately, nothing more needed, but the solution mentions opening "edge://policy/" and click "Reload Policies" or restart Edge, so you may need to do that as well.
